# Display sales group by week of the current month [LARAVEL]

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

so i wanna execute a query where i wanna display sales grouped by week of the current month
so the output will be
week 1
total : 300
week 2
total :200
week 3
total:10
week 4
total :56

but my queries display 5 weeks of the current month January (which we all know, one month is equal to 4 weeks)

here is my query

```
$currentMonth = Carbon::now("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")->month;
            $ordersByWeek = Order::select([
                DB::raw('sum(orderTotal) as total'),
                DB::raw('week(orderDate) as week'),
               // DB::raw('year(created_at) as year')
            ])
            ->groupBy(['week'])
            ->whereMonth('orderDate','=', $currentMonth)
            ->get();
```

please have a look the data that i dd($ordersByWeek)
[picture of dd data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYWVm.png)

[updated photo dd data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x18xD.png)

Comment: can you post the result you are getting

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai the dd data or bar chart? i display the query into a bar chart

Comment: I can't find any values in the the dd image that you have posted. Can you post the query result as array. you can call ```toArray()``` to convert collection to array.

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai i've updated my post :) do click the latest link photo